# What is the good practice for Updating sql table partially and keeping unedited values?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay guys, basically what i am trying to ask is this: I have a profile page on my website. Now, user enters first and last name. Later on they want to update their first name for example. Well, UPDATE syntax in a single query would update the whole field for that id right?

What I am trying to do is to hold on to the last name original value even if the table is updated for first name. I was thinking something like this would work.

```
$database = new Database;


if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
$id = isset($_POST['user_id'])?$_POST['user_id']:null;
$fname = isset($_POST['fname'])?$_POST['fname']:null;
$lname = isset($_POST['lname'])?$_POST['lname']:null;
$profession = isset($_POST['profession'])?$_POST['profession']:null;
$phone = isset($_POST['phone'])?$_POST['phone']:null;
$fax = isset($_POST['fax'])?$_POST['fax']:null;
$filtered_email = isset($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:null;
$workbio = isset($_POST['workbio'])?$_POST['workbio']:null;
$employers = isset($_POST['employers'])?$_POST['employers']:null;
$years = isset($_POST['years_in_industry'])?    $_POST['years_in_industry']:null;

$database->query('UPDATE users 
               SET firstname = COALESCE(:fname,firstname),
                   lastname = COALESCE(:lname,lastname),
                   profession = COALESCE(:profession,profession),
                   phone = COALESCE(:phone,phone),
                   fax = COALESCE(:fax,fax),
                   email = COALESCE(:email,email),
                   projects = COALESCE(:workbio,projects),
                   companies = COALESCE(:employers,companies),
                   exp_years = COALESCE(:years_in_industry,exp_years)
             WHERE user_id = :id');    
$database->bind(':id', $id);
$database->bind(':fname', $fname);
$database->bind(':lname', $lname);
$database->bind(':profession', $profession);
$database->bind(':phone', $phone);
$database->bind(':fax', $fax);
$database->bind(':email', $filtered_email);
$database->bind(':workbio', $workbio);
$database->bind(':employers', $employers);
$database->bind(':years_in_industry', $years);

$database->execute();
}
```

these are my database field names: user_id, firstname, lastname, profession, phone, fax, email, projects, companies, exp_years, acct_date

So here is my html form:

```
<div class="content">
    <!-- You only need this form and the form-basic.css -->
    <form class="form-basic" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <div class="form-title-row">
            <h1>Profile:</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>id:</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="id">
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Profession:</span>
                <input type="text" name="profession">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>First name</span>
                <input type="text" name="fname">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Last name</span>
                <input type="text" name="lname">
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Email:</span>
                <input type="email" name="email">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Phone:</span>
                <input type="tel" name="tel">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Fax:</span>
                <input type="tel" name="fax">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Companies I have worked with:</span>
                <textarea name="employers"></textarea>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Projects I've worked on:</span>
                <textarea name="workbio"></textarea>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Years I've been in my industry:</span>
                <select name="years_in_industry">
                    <option>1 year</option>
                    <option>2+ years</option>
                    <option>5+ years</option>
                    <option>10+ years</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label><span>Radio</span></label>
            <div class="form-radio-buttons">
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio">
                        <span>Radio option 1</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio">
                        <span>Radio option 2</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio">
                        <span>Radio option 3</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.

Comment: @Strawberry basically I am trying to understand how would update functionality work? will it update all fields in database even if you only update one form field?

Comment: Typically, you would build the query dynamically, and only submit those keys which have a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it right you can use just on UPDATE command to do so.

```
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $firstname = $_POST['fname']; 
    $lastname = $_POST['lname'];   
    $db->query('UPDATE users 
                   SET fname = COALESCE(:firstname,fname),
                       lname = COALESCE(:lastname,lname)
                 WHERE id = :id');
    $db->bind(':fname', $firstname);
    $db->bind(':lname', $lastname);
    $db->bind(':id', $_POST['id']); //it seems you forget the ID
    $db->execute();
}
```

Using the `COALESCE` function you only change the value of a field if it is not null, if it is it will use the same value that is on the database.

The `UPDATE` will only update the fields that you specify on the `SET` clause, every other field will remain with the same value.

Your code actually only are missing the bind for the ID value. It will actually work as you want. The code I suggested is an improvement to only run one update command instead of two.

**EDIT**

I actually made a little mistake. The `_POST` variable will evaluate to an error if a there is no such index on it, say you tried `$_POST['someVar']` but `someVar` doesn't exist in your form, it will return an error `Undefined index`

So in order to solve it you can edit your current code to:

```
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $id = isset($_POST['user_id'])?$_POST['user_id']:null;
    $fname = isset($_POST['fname'])?$_POST['fname']:null;
    $lname = isset($_POST['lname'])?$_POST['lname']:null;
    $profession = isset($_POST['profession'])?$_POST['profession']:null;
    $phone = isset($_POST['phone'])?$_POST['phone']:null;
    $fax = isset($_POST['fax'])?$_POST['fax']:null;
    $filtered_email = isset($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:null;
    $workbio = isset($_POST['workbio'])?$_POST['workbio']:null;
    $employers = isset($_POST['employers'])?$_POST['employers']:null;
    $years = isset($_POST['years_in_industry'])?$_POST['years_in_industry']:null;
```

This is a ternary operator where I'm chcking whether that variable comes from your form and if not, I assign null to it. A ternary condition is `condition?value if true:value if false;`

With this code your update command should work with the `coalesce` command.

Comment: thanks buddy that is exactly what I was asking for. Yes, I want to leave original data in the database alone and only change the one that user updates.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Comment: for some reason (maybe i am new here) it won't let me vote up your solution but as I am writing in this post, it helped me. thanks again.

Comment: That's no problem. Maybe some new rule based on reputation value.

Comment: Hey bud I got another question so in your code above which ones are the database field names and which ones are post values? Thanks.

Comment: Sure you can. Edit your question with it. And I will take a look

Comment: Take a look at my Edit.

Comment: the errors are gone but still it won't update. I think I have misplaced database fields names with post values in the query somewhere. I am so sorry to bother you so much but an you please take a look at my edit in the original post? thanks.

Comment: There are two possibilities that I can think of. 1- you don't have an input called `submit` which would be some kind of `<input type="submit">` instead of `<input type="submit" name="submit">` Note the attribute `name` and 2) the Id you passed does not belongs to the registry you are trying to update therefore you are not seeing any change.

Comment: I fixed the submit button but the id i am not sure. because in the database I got user_id as the field name.

Comment: Do you have an input with the name id? something like `<input type="text" name="id" value="someNumber">` where someNumber would be an ID from the database. the type can also be `type="hidden"`

Comment: I got this: <input type="text" name="id"> and also user shouldn't have to enter their id though I am doing this before I create my registration functionality for testing purposes. thanks buddy.

Comment: okay so I updated the field to this <input type="hidden" name="id" value="user_id"> where the value I putted my database field name for id.

Comment: Well there is your problem, since there is no value to the input id the update command are been evaluated to `where id = null` which will not update any row. I noticed another problem you have `name="id"` but you are trying to get `user_id` from the post `$id = isset($_POST['user_id'])?$_POST['user_id']:null;`, either fix the input with `name="user_id"`  or the php code to get id instead of user_id.

Comment: `value="user_id"` will not do any good, in fact it probably will lead to an error. ID should be an existant ID in the database which is probably a number. Something that I just noticed, are you trying to change an existing row or insert a new one?

Comment: trying to update the existing row but not all of its values/ columns just whichever column user wants to edit.

Comment: So your form must come from another query the fill all those input values. If you don't have an ID you will not have an update. Show how are your html form is filled

Comment: it is actually come from another page and also another query which is update query but I was wondering to know what you think buddy? do you think I should just make a change button call it change 1, 2, 3 and etc for each one of these fields and run their own separate queries?

Comment: So almost everything is missing from your current code. There is no value attribute in all form elements which is leading to no updates. If this page is coming from another page most likely you miss the values from there it would be something like (if you are sending it from another page as you say) `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$_POST['equivalent_variable_from_the_page_it_cames']?>">` without filling those value attributes you wont be able to change anything on your form, except for the fields like `<select ...`. Even though without the id it wont work